# Cats, More Cats, and Questions

Tags: riddle

Seemingly cat traps love medley,

Cats love the responses to me,

I help prevent a big clean up,

So you can type up Sup!

I trap cats like a boss,

since they can't get across,

I put a bounty on this guy,

 and attracted so many guys,

I look like an election just happened,

these people so happy for them votes

What am I? To be clear, I am a question and sorry for making the riddle rhyme!

Hint:

> The answer is a specific question...

Hint 2 and 3:

> The question is another SE question and there are no anagrams.

Comment: "Advertisements legally copy me" is an anagram of the first line.

Comment: Lol, but how did I even do that? That was not intended at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is referring to this question on Lifehacks.SE:

> **[How can I keep my cat off my keyboard?](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/9531)**

---

**Reasoning:**

*Seemingly cat traps love medley,*

> The highest-voted answer has a photo with a box labelled "Cat Trap", and is by user [Tom Medley](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/users/160).

*Cats love the responses to me,*

> There are 12 different answers, 4 of which have >30 upvotes.

*I help prevent a big clean up*

> By preventing a cat from sitting on your keyboard, you prevent having to erase all the text that was "typed" by the cat.

*So you can type up Sup!*

> I'm assuming this just means that you are able to type.

*I trap cats like a boss,*

> Again, the box is labelled "Cat Trap".

*since they can't get across,*

> Cats are distracted by the box, and can't get "across" to the keyboard.

*I put a bounty on this guy,*

> The top-voted (and accepted) answer was awarded a 500-rep bounty.

*and attracted so many guys,*

> 12 different people provided answers.

*I look like an election just happened,

these people so happy for them votes*

> There were an awful lot of upvotes on the question and several of the answers.

Comment: Well spotted! However did you find that?

Comment: @Irishpanda:  https://www.google.ca/#q=cat+medley+site:stackexchange.com

Comment: My Google-fu is weak. I bow to you sir.

Comment: Amazing!!! We have a winner!

Answer (score 4):

> It is a SE question, specifically, THIS QUESTION!

Comment: Nope, not this one

Answer (score 2):

Is it

> a Puzzling (or extensively, StackExchange) question?

Because

1.

> *Seemingly cat traps love medley, Cats love the responses to me, 
>
>  I trap cats like a boss, since they can't get across*  
>  Cats are users, that like to answer riddles (or in SE like them because they get through their problems)

2.

> *I help prevent a big clean up, So you can type up Sup!* 
>  In Puzzling you prevent the site closing posting many questions. In SE You help prevent a cleanup using tags that otherwise would be burninated

3.

> *I put a bounty on this guy, and attracted so many guys* 
>  Bounty part is self explaining, both in Puzzling or SE

4.

> *I look like an election just happened, these people so happy for them votes*  
>  You are happy if a comment or question gets many votes, right? :D

5.

> *What am I? To be clear, I am a question and sorry for making the riddle rhyme!* 
>  This is a question, even though it doesn't have question marks in it :D

Comment: Close but too broad

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure but is it...

> your own question in Meta Stack Exchange:
>  [What happened to the other people? My Impact (people reached) just dropped](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251661/what-happened-to-the-other-people-my-impact-people-reached-just-dropped)

and attracted so many guys

> The question is about reached people

I look like an election just happened,
these people so happy for them votes

> In the question the reason for lost people is that the other answers had got more votes.

Answer (score 0):

Just a wild guess.

Is it a

> Moderator

Comment: Nope... Read the hint